# Do we use past tense in a subordinating sentence when talking about a thing that a non-specific person might have done in the past?

Tags: grammar, tense, subordinate-clauses

When we use **when** or **if** or any other subordinating conjunctions (unless, because, and once, etc) to talk about a thing a non-specific person might have done in the past, do we use past tense?

Example 1: (when writing an article and referring to the reader's past.)

> (1) **If** you **had** an unhappy childhood, you are more protective of your kids.
>
> (2) **When** you **had** an unhappy childhood, you are more protective of your kids.
>
> (3) **Unless** you **had** a fortunate childhood, you are likely to be more protective of your kids.
>
> (4) If you are a beginner, your muscles can feel sore **because** you **started** lifting weights not long ago.

Example 2: (when talking about a non-specific person's past)

> (1) **If** a person **had** an unhappy childhood, he/she is more protective of his/her kids.
>
> (2) **When** a person **had** an unhappy childhood, he/she is more protective of his/her kids.
>
> (3) **Unless** a person **had** a fortunate childhood, he/she is likely to be more protective of his/her kids.
>
> (4) If a person is a beginner, his/her muscles can feel sore **because** he/she **started** lifting weights not long ago.

Comment: This non-specific thing is completely irrelevant...Also, your examples could have just as easily been about things, not a person....

Comment: Also, if you are referring to past actions, of course, you use the past tense.....How can you use a present tense to refer to the past?? Unless you use historical present, a literary thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be mentioned here.

First of all, the tense doesn't depend on whether you're referring to a specific person/entity or a "non-specific" person/entity. The only difference is that the verb would inflect (i.e. "you *eat*" would become "he *eat**s***"). For example:

> If **I** turn on the lights, **I** will waste electricity.
>
> If **you** turn on the lights, **you** will waste electricity.
>
> If **a person** turn*s* on the lights, **they** will waste electricity.
>
> If ____________ turn/turns on the lights, __________ will waste electricity.

Therefore, if you want to describe past actions, you can use a past tense, regardless of the person/entity.

---

Secondly, the tenses you're combining in your sentences make them a bit problematic.

When you're making conditional sentences with the past simple tense they should be constructed as follows:

> If *[past simple]*, ***[would + infinitive]***.
>
> If I **had** five dollars, I **would buy** a sandwich.

This means your sentences with "if" should state

> If you **had** an unhappy childhood, you **would be** more protective of *your* kids.
>
> If a person **had** an unhappy childhood, they **would be** more protective of *their* kids.

In your sentences using "when," the conjunction has the same sense as "if" when used in a "zero conditional" sentence:

> *When* you **turn** *(present)* on a television, it **makes** *(present)* noise.
>
> *If* you **turn** on a television, it **makes** noise. *("zero conditional")*

This means your sentences with "when" should state

> When you **have** an unhappy childhood, you **are** more protective of your kids.
>
> When a person **has** an unhappy childhood, they **are** more protective of their kids.

Sentences (3) and (4) in both cases seem fine to me otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I happened to recall that the word "because" can do the job like my examples: because a person [did] something in the past, that person [is] more something now. So you mean "because" and "once" and some subordinating conjunctions don't have to conform to the rule of sequence of tense and "when" and "if" have to conform to the rule of sequence of tense? Can we say: if/when a person [did] something in the past, that person [is] more something now?

Comment: @vincentlin I can't find any rule that says that **all** subordinating conjunctions have to follow a certain _rule_ regarding tense. That being said, the tenses you use depend on the **sense** of the subordinating conjunction. Your sentences with "if" are conditional sentences, and thus must follow tense rules of conditional sentences. Your sentences with "when" are examples of _**factual**_ conditional sentences (also called "_zero conditional_" sentences), which strictly use the present tense. (1/2)

Comment: Your example conjunctions also require you to analyse the **sense** behind them. You can definitely say "I **sing** _because_ I **like** it" and "We **take** the bus to work _because_ my husband **crashed** the car," but you can't say "I **talked** to Paul _because_ I **will be** curious about his family" because the combination of tenses doesn't make sense. Since "once" means "as soon as," you'd also have to watch the tenses. You can say "_Once_ he **left**, everyone **smiled**" and "_Once_ you **sing**, I **will cry**" but you can't say "_Once_ she **ate**, everyone **will eat**." (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Tense depends on the time of the action of the verb, NOT on whether the subject is specific or non-specific.

Subject : You (specific) :

> Zero conditional : If you have an unhappy childhood, you are more protective of your kids.
>
> Conditional type 1 : If you have an unhappy childhood, you will be more protective of your kids.
>
> Conditional type 2 : If you had an unhappy childhood, you would be more protective of your kids.
>
> Conditional type 3 : If you had had an unhappy childhood, you would have been more protective of your kids.
>
> ---

Subject : a person (non-specific):

> Zero conditional : If a person has an unhappy childhood, he/she is more protective of his/her kids.
>
> Conditional type 1 : If a person has an unhappy childhood, he/she will be more protective of his/her kids.
>
> Conditional type 2 : If a person had an unhappy childhood, he/she would be more protective of his/her kids.
>
> Conditional type 3 : If a person had had an unhappy childhood, he/she would have been more protective of his/her kids.
>
> ---

Note : The same thing happens with unless or when-clause :

> e.g., Zero conditional :
>
> When you have an unhappy childhood, you are more protective of your kids.
>
> When a person has an unhappy childhood, they are more protective of their kids.